# Twilio Dial multiple numbers - one called party hangs up

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am confused on the situation when Twilio calls multiple numbers using Dial and Number nouns.

```
<Dial action="http://example.com/twilio/call/after_call_closest_workers" callerId="+358111111444" timeout="20">
    <Number statusCallback="http://example.com/twilio/call/status/worker" statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallbackMethod="POST">+35851111111</Number>
    <Number statusCallback="http://example.com/twilio/call/status/worker" statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallbackMethod="POST">+35852222222</Number>
    <Number statusCallback="http://example.com/twilio/call/status/worker" statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallbackMethod="POST">+3583333333</Number>
    <Number statusCallback="http://example.com/twilio/call/status/worker" statusCallbackEvent="answered completed" statusCallbackMethod="POST">+3584444444</Number>
</Dial>
```

If one called party hangs up during the call, the other parties are still called AFAIK. However, what is the call status returned when this party hangs up? Is it answered/busy/something?

Couldn't find anything related to this in the docs.
Also, if someone found a way to test this without actually calling/wasting money, would appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 2):

More details on how it works is here:

Dialing Multiple Numbers Simultaneously with Twilio

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html

The dialed party that answered cancels all the other call legs. When the person that did answer hangs-up, the Dial action URL fires, DialCallStatus = completed.

Comment: I mentioned the case of rejected call. rejected != answered